# How to move all my content in the middle using FLEXBOX

Tags: html, css

[The Image photo for the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQUSz.png)I have been trying to put the display flex property in my card-container class , and use the justify-content property to center it , but it is not making any change to the content inside the box , can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong , I was just practicing something from frontendio, plus there was also this problem with my first button , the one to place order , even though I had set the padding to 0.75 rem on both top and bottom and 4rem on left and right it was still uneven on left and right

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Order summary card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="Card-main">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="top-container">
        <img src="images/illustration-hero.svg" class="main-image">
      </div>
      <div class="middle-container">
        <h1 class="title">
          Order Summary
        </h1>
        <br>
        <p class="summary">
          You can now listen to millions of songs ,audiobooks and podcasts on any device anywhere you like 

        </p>
        <div class="plan-container">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <button class="btn" type="button">
          Proceed to Payment
        </button>

        <button class="btn-cancel">
          Cancel Order
        </button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Red+Hat+Display);
:root{
--Pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 94%);
--Bright-blue: hsl(245, 75%, 52%);



--Very-pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 98%);
--Desaturated-blue: hsl(224, 23%, 55%);
--Dark-blue: hsl(223, 47%, 23%);
}
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Body Backgrounds */
body{
background-image:url(/images/pattern-background-desktop.svg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:hsl(225, 100%, 94%) ;
font-family: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;
}


/* Card Container */

.card-container{
    width:33%;
    height:80%;
    margin: 3em auto;
    background-color:hsl(225, 100%, 98%) ;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;

}
.main-image{
    width: 100%;;
}
.top-container{
    margin:0 0 2em 0;
}
h1.title{
    font-weight: 900;
}
p{
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin:2em auto;
    color:var(--Desaturated-blue);
}
.bottom-container{
    width:90%;
}
.btn{
    background-color: var(--Bright-blue);
    color: var(--Pale-blue);
    padding:0.75rem 6rem;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border:none;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:12px;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--Pale-blue);
    color: var(--Bright-blue);
}
.btn-cancel{
    background-color: white;
    color:var(--Desaturated-blue);
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin:2em auto;


}
.btn-cancel:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Red+Hat+Display);
:root{
--Pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 94%);
--Bright-blue: hsl(245, 75%, 52%);



--Very-pale-blue: hsl(225, 100%, 98%);
--Desaturated-blue: hsl(224, 23%, 55%);
--Dark-blue: hsl(223, 47%, 23%);
}
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Body Backgrounds */
body{
background-image:url(/images/pattern-background-desktop.svg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:hsl(225, 100%, 94%) ;
font-family: "Red Hat Display", sans-serif;
}


/* Card Container */

.card-container{
    width:33%;
    height:80%;
    margin: 3em auto;
    background-color:hsl(225, 100%, 98%) ;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;    
}
.main-image{
    width: 100%;;
}
.top-container{
    margin:0 0 2em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
h1.title{
    font-weight: 900;
}
p{
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 2em;
    margin:2em auto;
    color:var(--Desaturated-blue);
}
.bottom-container{
    width:90%;
}
.btn{
    background-color: var(--Bright-blue);
    color: var(--Pale-blue);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border:none;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:12px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.btn:hover{
    background-color: var(--Pale-blue);
    color: var(--Bright-blue);
}
.btn-cancel{
    background-color: white;
    color:var(--Desaturated-blue);
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:0.9rem;
    margin:2em auto;


}
.btn-cancel:hover{
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Order summary card</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="Card-main">
    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="top-container">
        <img src="images/illustration-hero.svg" class="main-image">
      </div>
      <div class="middle-container">
        <h1 class="title">
          Order Summary
        </h1>
        <br>
        <p class="summary">
          You can now listen to millions of songs ,audiobooks and podcasts on any device anywhere you like 

        </p>
        <div class="plan-container">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-container">
        <button class="btn" type="button">
          Proceed to Payment
        </button>

        <button class="btn-cancel">
          Cancel Order
        </button>

      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything works well, just a single thing the image , is not fitting the corners of the main container when i run this code and why are we using width 100% with the main button

Comment: width: 100%; for the main button makes the button to occupy the full container, 100% of it.

Comment: Can you please share the image of your output, so that I can try to fit the image in corners of the main container?

Comment: check the main question , I have added a link to the ss

Comment: Hi, try adding width: 100%; to the .top-container class. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

just make changes to 2 css classes

```
.card-container{
    width:33%;
    height:80%;
    margin: 3em auto;
    background-color:hsl(225, 100%, 98%) ;
    border-radius: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}

.bottom-container{
    width:90%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Why so? Like what is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Flexbox is all about boxes and block level element whereas text-align is about text and inline level element. so the divs inside your card-container are blocks and `justify-content: center` is applied to them but not the contents inside them (i.e `h1`, `p`)..by default they are left aligned here. so you have to manually go to each tag (h1, p) and apply `text-align: center`. But applying `text-align: center` in parent div(`card-container`) does this job even for the children inside it. So you are basically changing this from the parent only.